# Does Visual Studio Code Depend On The .NET Framework and if so what version?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm working on making a installation package for [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) and can't find any documentation for it's dependencies does it require a version of the [.NET Framework](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet-framework) and if so what version?

I saw that the [Visual Studio Code Chocolatey package](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/vscode) requires the [.NET Framework](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet-framework) 4.5.2 but on the [Visual Studio Code requirements page](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/supporting/requirements) there are no dependencies listed...

Comment: VSC is JavaScript based, no .NET dependency

Comment: If i might ask, why are you not using Visual Studio? 
(There you get everything you need for .NET development)

Comment: Chocolatey isn't an official installer, but a repackaging made by a third party. Maybe it bundles some plugins that happen to require .NET or simply bundles Framework because they like it, but the the program itself doesn't require it.

Comment: The comments on the Chocolatey page asking about the .NET dependency are 3 years old; the package itself doesn't list that dependency any more and neither does the official page here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/windows